# How to add today's time to any date object and getISOString?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, ng-bootstrap

I have a `ngbDatePicker` which helps me to pick a date. Then it returns an object like this:

```
{year:2020,month:12,day:03}
```

I'd like to get an `ISOString` of this date with today's time(current). So if time is 18:42 I should be able to get something like this:
`2020-12-03T18:42:00.000Z`

To do that I parsed object and made date firstly
(model is the object holds date like above)

```
var date = new Date(this.model.year + "-" + this.model.month + "-" + this.model.day);
 //then to add today's time I found solution below on the internet whcih didn't work for me
var date2 = new Date(date);
var isoDateTime = new Date(date2 .getTime() - (date2 .getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString();
```

Here isoDateTime returns  `2020-12-10T03:00:00.000Z` which is not I want.

How to solve this?

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbdatepicker-eyy7sb?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.ts)

Comment: You could use something like https://momentjs.com/ to format the date. Then you could so something like moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') to get 2020-12-03, or just moment().format() will create  2020-12-03T16:03:52+00:00

Comment: I don't wanna use moment.js to handle this only

Comment: If you want local time, you should not append the Z, which indicates UTC.

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek Did any of the given answers answer your question? Don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear or was misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the time part of a `Date` object and combine it with `this.model`:

```
var date2 = new Date();

var date = new Date(this.model.year, this.model.month-1, this.model.day,
                    date2.getHours(), date2.getMinutes(), date2.getSeconds());

var isoDateTime = date.toISOString();

console.log(isoDateTime);
```

The month parameter is 0 based, so we have to substract 1 from the month.
Result (I chose Dec.1st 2020 in the Datepicker):

```
2020-12-01T19:22:42.000Z
```

Try on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbdatepicker-kzakte?file=app/datepicker-popup.ts)

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants as it takes local values but returns a UTC timestamp. The use of Date.now in new Date(Date.now()) is totally redundant.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the question is not 100% clear but the given example: (*should be able to get something like this: 2020-12-03T18:42:00.000Z*) shows a Z for UTC. I removed the redundant Date.now().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single Date for the time and append it to values from the object:

```js
function myISOString(obj) {
  let z = n=>('0'+n).slice(-2);
  return `${obj.year}-${z(obj.month)}-${z(obj.day)}T${new Date().toTimeString().substring(0,8)}`;
}

let obj = {year:2020, month:12, day: 3};

console.log(myISOString(obj));
```

PS the use of leading zeros like `03` for numbers should be avoided as once upon a time that notation indicated octal values (but not any more), so `09` might be confusing.